# How should concrete types return an instance of an interface in a loosely-coupled way?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, loose-coupling

I have an `IDirectory` interface and a `Directory` class that implements it.
I need to create an `IDirectoryEnumerator` which just has a method that looks like so:

```
IEnumerable<IDirectory> GetDirectories();
```

So I created a `DirectoryEnumerator` class, but I'm not sure which `IDirectory` to return in `GetDirectories()`, since **I want to keep my code loosely-coupled**.

Should I use generics with constraints to `IDirectory` somehow?
Should I get it somehow through a DI container?
Should something like that be tightly-coupled and I should focus on a specific concrete type?
Or is there another better option?

*Note: concrete types of `IDirectory` in my example don't have any default constructors and are immutable.*

Comment: What is `Directory` and why do you implement that interface on it? Will there ever be more implementations of `IDictionary` and do you intend to hide behavior behind this interface or just data?

Comment: @Steven Currently there is just a `Directory` and a `DesignDirectory` for WPF blendability. But either way this will allow me to extend my software in unexpected ways, so it's pretty vital imo. This interface also has a behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the concrete `IDirectoryEnumerator` implementation accept some sort of factory (e.g. `IDirectoyFactory`) through the constructor, and then use a parametrized method in that factory to create concrete types of `IDirectory`.

This also makes testing easier and enables you to use a DI container to inject the dependencies.

EXAMPLE:

```
public interface IDirectoryEnumerator
{
    IEnumerable<IDirectory> GetDirectories();
}

public class DirectoryEnumImpl : IDirectoryEnumerator
{
    private readonly IDirectoryFactory _directoryFactory;
    
    public DirectoryEnumImpl(IDirectoryFactory directoryFactory)
    {
        _directoryFactory = directoryFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IDirectory> GetDirectories()
    {
        // you can use the factory here
    }
}

public interface IDirectoryFactory
{
    IDirectory CreateDirectory(DirectoryType directoryType);
}

public class DirectoryFactoryImpl : IDirectoryFactory
{
    IDirectory CreateDirectory(DirectoryType directoryType)
    {
        if (directoryType == DirectoryType.DIR_A)
            return new Dir_A();

        // the same goes for other types.
    }
}

public enum DirectoryType 
{
    DIR_A, DIR_B, // etc ...
}
```

Comment: Is this a known pattern? Also, how would `IDirectoyFactory` look like?

Comment: @Ken The Factory pattern is well known. I have edited my answer, please check edit.

Comment: So ultimately the directory factory is tightly-coupled with a directory implementation?

Comment: @Ken, You cannot avoid that in your case. Someone has to create instances of `IDirectory` because they cannot be injected.